# Laravel : Eloquent Relationships not work. Cannot show relationships in view

Tags: php, database, laravel, backend

I cannot show relationships in view after I set Eloquent Relationships in Model already.

In Model: Art_obj

```
class Art_obj extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'art_objs';
    protected $fillable = ['Id_no','Artist','Year','Title','Description','Origin','Epoch','Picture','Type_of_art'];

    public function Painting(){
        return $this->hasOne(Painting::class,'Id_no');
    }

}
```

In Model: Painting

```
class Painting extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'paintings';
    protected $fillable = ['art_obj_Id_no','Paint_type','Drawn_on','Style'];

    public function Art_obj(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Art_obj::class,'Id_no');
    }

}
```

In PaintingController

```
public function index()
    {
        $paintings = Painting::with('Art_obj');
        return view('ArtObj.Painting', compact('paintings'));
    }
```

in Painting.blade.php

```
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> 
                <tr> 
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Paint type</th> 
                    <th>Drawn on</th>
                    <th>Style</th>
                    </tr> 
                        @foreach($paintings as $row) 
                    <tr> 
                    <td>{{$row->Art_obj->Title}}</td>
                    <td>{{$row['Paint_type']}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$row['Drawn_on']}}</td> 
                    <td>{{$row['Style']}}</td> 
                </tr> 
                @endforeach 
            </table>
```

It does not have any field show in view.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yr7VC.png)

Comment: ```Id_no``` is foreign key of ```paintings``` table in ```art_objs``` table or Please display both table structure if possible

Comment: Don't camelize the name with underline. It's best to camelize the model name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using `id` as your model's primary key, you need to set the primary key property in your models:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'Id_no';
```

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a `protected $primaryKey` property to override this convention.
>
> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing property on your model to false. If your primary key is not an integer, you should set the `protected $keyType` property on your model to string.

In addition, the relation must set the correct foreign and owner keys:

```
public function Art_obj(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Art_obj::class,'Id_no', 'art_obj_Id_no');
}
```

and then retrieve the data:

```
$paintings = Painting::with('Art_obj')->get();
```

You should also check if the relation exists before attempting to access it:

```
@foreach($paintings as $row) 
<tr> 
   @if (!is_null($row->Art_obj))
   <td>{{$row->Art_obj->Title}}</td>
   @else
   <td>No Title</td>
   @endif
   <td>{{$row->Paint_type}}</td> 
   <td>{{$row->Drawn_on}}</td> 
   <td>{{$row->Style}}</td> 
</tr> 
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

You have not fetched data yet. Change your query to:

```
$paintings = Painting::with('Art_obj')->get();
```

Comment: then it says 'Trying to get property 'Title' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\museum-DB-Project\resources\views\ArtObj\Painting.blade.php)'What is that mean?

Comment: It means your Art_obj is empty

Comment: This is like you are not getting anything in this. If your art_obj_Id_no field can be empty than add a check in blade before showing that it exists or not and if it can't be empty then try changing it to $row->ArtObj->Title, if it does not work then try first printing the paintings object like this print_r($paintings) or print_r($paintings->toArray()) and check with what index it gives artists to you.